# How to raise event when new event has been written?

Tags: c#

How do i raise my own event in c#  when there has been "new audit event" operation to the computer Event Log ( in the manage section ...).

Comment: I have seen worse questions getting upvotes. Why was this downvoted?

Comment: You want your program to detect when the Windows event log is updated?

Comment: @UrbanEsc  : you right sorry. Bobby fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this code-project sample: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/rteventreader.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

http://ashishware.com/websocksample.shtml